# Issue with Navbar that works on hover on desktop screen and works on click on mobile

Tags: javascript

i have setup a bootstrap navbar with javascript program that works on hover on Desktop screen and works on click on mobile and tablet screen. but i have an issue that whenever on desktop screen i click on any navbar any button it start toggling. so i have to refresh the page again to make it work normally.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    });
} else {
        $(function(){
            $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
            }, function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
      </div>
   

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try mynavbar framework _nel, they make hover on the desktop and click on mobile

http://getnel.github.io

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't provide *link only* answers. And btw, Rana is already using the bootstrap framework and I'm not sure whether (s)he is looking for another framework. Can't you find a solution for thie problem without another framework?

Comment: You must disclose your affiliation with your own projects.

Comment: because bootstrap already has its own function, I'm not sure to be able to handle it, but if you want to know how to make navbar like your question, try looking at the _nel framework code.